# My pc sends many ARP requests to router over wifi

Tags: arp

My pc sends many arp requests to the router over WiFi .. why is that?

[image]

Also, why does the router send ARP requests to the whole net from time to time?

Comment: Can you clarify the second question please? Do you have a capture showing that as well?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the timestamps, it looks like the device 192.168.1.13 has an ARP cache timer of 10 seconds. So after 10 seconds it flushes the entry from the ARP cache, and (if there is traffic to be sent) it sends a new ARP request.